# How to sort last four files in a google drive folder via google-apps-script?

Tags: sorting, google-apps-script, gmail

I have some google sheets in google drive. I am trying to send only last four months files in google drive to email. The problem is the months are defined in the file's name. So there is no timestamp

So far, I am searching the files by title contains "Mar 2019" or title contains "Apr 2019". if like this, I have to change the code every month after adding a file to the google drive.

```
function checkSales(){

  var file, files = DriveApp.getFolderById("").searchFiles('title 
  contains "Mar 2019" or title contains "Apr 2019" or title contains "May 
  2019" or title contains "Jun 2019"')
  var body = '';
  var subject = [];
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    file = files.next();
    var activeSpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.open(file);
    var spreadsheetName = activeSpreadSheet.getName(); // Added
      var sheets = activeSpreadSheet.getSheets();
      for (var sheetIndex = 0; sheetIndex < sheets.length; sheetIndex++) {
        var sheet = sheets[sheetIndex];
        var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
        var resultArr = [];
        for (var i=1;i<data.length;i++) {
          for (var j=11;j<19;j++) {
            var cellVal = data[i][j];
            if (cellVal > 0) {
              resultArr.push([data[i][0],data[0][j],cellVal]);
            }
          }
        }
      }

  }
```

I want the output to send the last four files in the google drive to email.

Comment: This is problematic since even the code that you have proposed requires some editing. Would you please advise what is the file naming algorithm (and give an example)? Are all the relevant files kept in the same folder, and are these the **only** files in that folder? On a tangent, might it not be just as easy to browse and choose the specific files from a sidebar, and have these automatically attached in the email?

Comment: The `getLastUpdated()` attribute returns the date the File was last updated. Select this field, sort on on it, then select the first N items for your attachments.

Answer (score 2):

- You want to automatically create the search query using a script.
- You want to search files using the created search query.
- For example, when today is July 2019, you want to create the search query like below.

  - `'title contains "Mar 2019" or title contains "Apr 2019" or title contains "May 2019" or title contains "Jun 2019"'`

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification? Please think of this as one of several answers.

#### Modification points:

- At first, a JSON object is created as follows.

  - `{0: "Jan", 1: "Feb", 2: "Mar", 3: "Apr", 4: "May", 5: "Jun", 6: "Jul", 7: "Aug", 8: "Sep", 9: "Oct", 10: "Nov", 11: "Dec"}`.
  - Using this object and the date object, the filenames are created.

**At first, please check the values of above JSON object I prepared. If there are modification values, please modify them. If the wrong values are included, the files cannot be retrieved. Please be careful this.**

#### Modified script:

Please modify as follows.

From:

```
var file, files = DriveApp.getFolderById("").searchFiles('title contains "Mar 2019" or title contains "Apr 2019" or title contains "May 2019" or title contains "Jun 2019"')
```

To:

```
var months = {0: "Jan", 1: "Feb", 2: "Mar", 3: "Apr", 4: "May", 5: "Jun", 6: "Jul", 7: "Aug", 8: "Sep", 9: "Oct", 10: "Nov", 11: "Dec"};
var date   = new Date();
var y  = date.getFullYear();
var m = date.getMonth();
var fileNames = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  m--; // For example, when today is July, you need June, May, Apr and Mar.
  if (m < 0) {
    m += 12;
    y--;
  }
  fileNames.push(months[m] + " " + y);
  //  m--; // For example, when today is July, you need July, June, May and Apr.
}
var searchQuery = fileNames.map(function(e) {return 'title contains "' + e + '"'}).join(" or ");
var file, files = DriveApp.getFolderById("root").searchFiles(searchQuery);
```

#### Note:

- I couldn't understand about `var spreadsheetNames = DriveApp.searchFiles(`. I think that when your script is saved, an error occurs.

  - This is also mentioned by [Tedinoz's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56895629/how-to-sort-last-four-files-in-a-google-drive-folder-via-google-apps-script#comment100337614_56895629).
- In this sample script, when today is July, June, May, Apr and Mar are retrieved. If you want to retrieve July, June, May and Apr, please modify the commented out of `m--;` of above script.

#### References:

- [getFullYear()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getFullYear)
- [getMonth()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: As u said, what should i modify to retrieve July, June, May and Apr?

Comment: @Sriram I deeply apologize for my poor English skill. When today is July, when you need July, June, May and Apr, please use ``m--;`` below ``fileNames.push(months[m] + " " + y);``. At that time, please comment out ``m--;`` below ``for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {``.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
function getLastFourMonthFileIds(){
  var nA=['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Nov','Dec'];
  var mA=[];
  for(var i=0;i<4;i++) {
    var dt=new Date(new Date().getFullYear(),new Date().getMonth()-i,new Date().getDate());
    mA.push(nA[dt.getMonth()]+dt.getFullYear());
  }
  var fA=[];
  var files = DriveApp.getFolderById("").getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS);
  while(files.hasNext()) {
    var file=files.next();
    if(mA.indexOf(file.getName())>-1) {
      fA.push(file.getId());
    } 
  }
  Logger.log(fA);
  return fA();
}
```

Comment: Does this code make an assumption about how files are named?

Comment: It does. This is the name of the file: `nA[dt.getMonth()]+dt.getFullYear()`

Answer (score 0):

A code example using the `getLastUpdated()` attribute.

---

```
function so5689562902() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetname = "56895629";
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetname);
  sheet.activate;

  // sundry variables
  var filearray = [];
  var filedetail = [];
  var emailarray = [];
  var emailattachments = [];
  var numberReq = 4;

  // get the files from the folder
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("<<insert Folder ID>>");
  var files = folder.getFiles();
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    filedetail=[];
    //Logger.log("DEBUG: file name: "+file.getName()+", file ID: "+file.getId()+", last updated: "+file.getLastUpdated());
    filedetail.push(file.getName());
    filedetail.push(file.getId());
    filedetail.push(file.getLastUpdated());
    // build cumulative array
    filearray.push(filedetail);
  }

  // sort the array by date updated
  filearray.sort(function(x,y){
    var xp = x[2];
    var yp = y[2];
    return xp == yp ? 0 : xp > yp ? -1 : 1;
  });

  // get just the first N files
  for (i=0;i<numberReq;i++){

    filedetail=[]; 
    filedetail.push(filearray[i][0] ); // name
    filedetail.push(filearray[i][1] ); // file ID
    filedetail.push(filearray[i][2] ); // last updated
    // build the array of email files
    emailarray.push(filedetail);
    emailattachments.push(filearray[i][1])
  }

  // display the details for proof
  //var arraylen = emailarray.length;
  //Logger.log("DEBUG: the array length = "+arraylen);
  //var targetrange = sheet.getRange(2,1,arraylen, 3);
  //Logger.log("DEBUG: the target range = "+targetrange.getA1Notation());
  //targetrange.setValues(emailarray);

  // sample sendEmail.
  // email attachments are included in the options
  //GmailApp.sendEmail(<<recipient>>, <<Subject>>,nonhtmlmessage, {from:senderemail,htmlBody: htmlmessage,name: senderName,replyTo:senderemail ,attachments: emailattachments  }); 

}
```